# How to insert data from one table to another from two oracle database servers with public database link?

Tags: database, oracle

I am going to insert data from `table2` to `table1` and the two tables are in different database, different servers.

There are public database links for both database. In the details of the public database links, there are names of owner, db_link, username and host.

I want to ask how to use the public database links to insert the data from `table2` to `table1`, thanks.

I have tried something like

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT 'xxxx, xxxx, xxxx', columns_from_table2
FROM table2@"db_link"
WHERE criteria;
```

but it prompts out an error message of

```
ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found
02019. 00000 -  "connection description for remote database not found"
```

Comment: Please post code with what you have already tried.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you performing the insert from?  Is it from one of the databases?  Are you trying to copy all the data from one table to another?  Are both tables identical in structure? Is the target table empty? And I could go on... You need to add a lot more details.

Comment: I perform the insert from at database1 and I am trying to copy some records from table2 to table1. However, I am not going to copy the whole table. For example, I want to insert something like
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT 'xxxx, xxxxx, xxxx', columna_from_table2, columnb_from_table2 FROM table2
WHERE <criteria>;

Comment: Based on the error you are getting, it isn't a problem with your `insert` statement, rather, your db link appears to be invalid.  If you do a simple `SELECT * FROM table2@db_link WHERE rownum < 2`, are you able to get something from that?  If not, then start by configuring your db link correctly.

Comment: Sorry, may i know how to set up the link? Since I have performed 'Test Database Link' successfully using Oracle SQL Developer, I don't know where the problem is actually.

Comment: Are you certain your database link is named `"db_link"` all lower case? Database object names in Oracle are typically all upper case unless you wrapped the name in double quotes to over ride the implicit case conversion.  Try `select db_link from all_db_links where regexp_like( db_link, 'db_link', 'i');` to find out the true name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not using the correct dblink. Try this and tell me:

select * from dual@"db_link"

select * from dba_db_links where db_link = "[your_db_link_name]"